# Access Report - show current recordsource of another form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a report that displays another form's recordsource. When I add some record on this form and click for report, this records is not being displayed. How can I achieve displaying what is on screen - allways ? Here is my simple code for report:

```
Private Sub cmdOpenReport_Click()

   DoCmd.OpenReport "MyReport", acViewReport

End Sub

Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)

   Me.RecordSource = Forms![MyForm].Form.RecordSource

End Sub
```

Comment: I am confused. Isn't the form already displaying what is on it? Why do you need a report? Also, check the Me.RecordSource to ensure you are requesting the correct data.

Comment: I have a form. When I open It, there are certain records in It. If I click on button for Report, these records are displayed. BUT, If I enter a new record (in continous form) AND then click again on Report button, this new record is not being displayed - that is what problem is. I need a report for printing, e-mailing, making PDF...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an answer, I knew It's not so easy (in click event of OpenReport button):

```
Dim strWhere As String

    Me.Dirty = False

    With Me.Recordset.Clone
        Do Until .EOF
            strWhere = strWhere & "," & !ID
            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With
    strWhere = Mid(strWhere, 2)
    DoCmd.OpenReport "MyReport", acViewReport, WhereCondition:="ID In (" & strWhere & ")
```

Answer provided by Leigh Purvis (Access MVP), a BIG thanks once more !!

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the Report before re-opening it and save the new record.

In the click event of your Open Report button insert the following:

```
Private Sub OpenReport_Click()

    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
    DoCmd.Close acReport, "Test1", acSaveYes
    DoCmd.OpenReport "Test1", acViewPreview

End Sub
```

Comment: no, this doesn't work, Unfortunlly recordsource of form still stays same as on  Load.

Comment: Maybe problem is because this form's recordsource is opened via "Search" form in first place ? And then, when you add new records, recordsource stays same ? Should I post that code too ?

Comment: This should work. I tested it with a continuous form. I did mistakenly specify the Open Form button, but I meant the Open Report button.

Comment: No It doesn't, and I think I know where problem is now. I didn't mention one thing - form that has records is actually a form which displays results via SQL statement. So, when form with records opens, It's recordsource is defined via SQL clause. And looks like that once you set recordsource, you cannot reset It and use recordsource as in screen.

Comment: I do not think the record-source makes a difference. Is the Open Report button on the form that you want to show report results? Please provide any code or properties you think are relevant.

Comment: Yes, Open_Report button is on the form where records are. There isn't any code to provide, I can explain without....There is a "search" form with a button to find records I wish - this opens form where Report button is, and you see records that you wanted. Now. from this point on, when I enter some new records - I want everything seen on my report, new records too.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the sub above to ensure it is executing properly?

Answer (score 0):

Try requerying your Forms Recordset before opening the report:

```
Private Sub cmdOpenReport_Click()
   Me.FilterOn = False
   Me.Requery
   DoCmd.OpenReport "MyReport", acViewReport
End Sub
```

Comment: this doesn't work, I allready tried that before. Requery removes last saved record from screen, and Report still doesn't show correctly.

Comment: I think we got a clue why this isn't working when you said: "Maybe problem is because this form's recordsource is opened via "Search" form in first place ? " below. I'm not 100% sure what method your "Search" form is using but I imagine it's a filter. Thus see my modified answer above.

Comment: Yes, you are right, It's a filter, but an SQL filter - whatever I type in Texboxes, my form then opens If there are some matches. I thought this was not important, but now I see It is. Your code doesn't work, It displays me all records from Table recordsource, although including new ones.

Comment: If it's a SQL Filter you will have to find a way to clear it. If you used a form Filter in your search form it may simplify it as you will be able to clear it like my example above... then reapply when needed.