# Access report - Recordsetclone as. Recordsource

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form, which has button for report. I want to set Report .Recordsource to whatever on screen is, so basically I need .RecordsetClone of form send to Report. Here is what I tried, but It doesn't work:

```
Me.Recordsource= Forms!Myform.RecordsetClone
```

I get an invalid argument on that. Any ideas how to solve this ?

EDIT:

I tried this too - this button is placed on form which has records and opens Report :

```
Private Sub cmdOpenReport_Click()

DoCmd.OpenReport "MyReport", acViewReport
   Reports![MyReport].RecordSource = Me.RecordSource
Reports![MyReport].Filter = Me.Filter
Reports![MyReport].FilterOn = True

End Sub
```

Comment: `Recordsource` wants a string (query or SQL). You can try `Set Me.Recordset = Forms!Myform.RecordsetClone` but I'm not sure if this works.

Comment: @Andre, when pasting this in Report_Open event, I got error: "This feature is only available  in an ADP". Looks like It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gustav, this is correct answer. I have opened another thread for that, but I wasn't aware of what is wrong and where. Sorry for crossposting. here is link to my thread: 
[Access Report - show current recordsource of another form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36631021/access-report-show-current-recordsource-of-another-form/36632324?noredirect=1#comment60907083_36632324)

```
Dim strWhere As String

        Me.Dirty = False

        With Me.Recordset.Clone
            Do Until .EOF
                strWhere = strWhere & "," & !ID
                .MoveNext
            Loop
        End With
        strWhere = Mid(strWhere, 2)
        DoCmd.OpenReport "MyReport", acViewReport, WhereCondition:="ID In (" & strWhere & ")
```

Moderators can delete one of the threads, I can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, but you may get away with:

```
Me.RecordSource = Forms!Myform.RecordSource
```

though that will not include a filter applied to the form. However, the Filter can be copied the same way, and then:

```
Me.Filter = Forms!Myform.Filter  
Me.FilterOn = True
```

while sorting must be specified in the report the usual way.

**Proof of concept**

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)

    If MsgBox("Mod 2?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Select") = vbYes Then
        Me.RecordSource = "Select * From TestTable Where Id Mod 2 = 0"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Gustav, where and how exactly should I try this, in Report_Open event ? I tried, but nothing happens. Or do I have to do something in button_click event - where I open Report (DoCmd.Openreport,"myReport",AcViewPreview)

Comment: I would use the click event - but then you must replace `Me` with `Reports.[NameOfYourReport]`

Comment: check my edited question If this is what you meant. It's not working. Try testing with some blank continous form - enter 2 rows and then open report without closing form, to see those 2 rows - you'll see only one, last saved record.

Comment: Then revert, this time using the `Report_Load` event.

Comment: It doesn't work either. As I said in beginning, I need to set RecordsetClone somehow to Report. I forgot to mention that form which has record is actually opened in desired records, via SQL. So basically Recordsource of form is defined on load. And looks like you can't re-define It again, so It must be a way to make just a RecordsetClone.

Comment: Then something else is going on. The code added to my answer works as intended and is simple to test.